# Is this a correct implementation of the strategy pattern (JAVA, Fly method of ducks)?

Tags: java, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I just want a quick lookover that I implemented the different fly strategies correctly.

The program simply consists of a **duck** class that uses an **interface** for its **fly method**. The interface has different implementations (namely *SimpleFly* and *NoFly*), and a switch statement chooses the correct method based on the specie enum.

As I understand, the strategy pattern is meant to avoid duplicate code between child classes at the same level, which decreases maintainability and extensibility. So instead we abstract out the related algorithms to interfaces and choose them as needed.

CODE:

```
package DesignPatterns;

//Here we will separate the fly method of ducks into implementations of an internface and then instantiate ducks with those attributes

interface IFly {
    
    public void fly();
    
}

//These are called strategies
class SimpleFly implements IFly {

    @Override
    public void fly() {
        System.out.println("Quack Quack i am flying in the air");
    }
    
}

class NoFly implements IFly {
    
    @Override
    public void fly() {
        System.out.println("I cannot fly.");
    }
    
}

//Now the base class just has to implement one of these strategies
class Duck {
    
    private IFly flyType;
    
    public enum SPECIE {
        WILD, CITY, RUBBER
    }
    
    public Duck(SPECIE specie) {
        switch(specie) {
            
            //Here just select the algorithms you want to assign to each type of DUCK. More flexible than horizontal code between species.
            case WILD:
            case CITY:
                this.flyType = new SimpleFly();
                break;
            case RUBBER:
                this.flyType = new NoFly();
                break;
            default:
                //If a new enum is defined but no definition yet, this stops code from breaking
                this.flyType = new SimpleFly();
        }
    }
    
    public void fly() {
        flyType.fly();
    }
    
}
```

The output is correct as in this example:

```
        Duck rubberDuck = new Duck(Duck.SPECIE.RUBBER);
        Duck normalDuck = new Duck(Duck.SPECIE.WILD);
        
        rubberDuck.fly();
        normalDuck.fly();
```

Yields:

```
I cannot fly.
Quack Quack i am flying in the air
```

Thank you in advance and please let me know about any gaps in my knowledge,
Sshawarma

Comment: More or less it is correct. You can use a bit of inversion of control to avoid creating the strategies inside the class using them. And with Strategy pattern you should be able to change the strategy (for the same object) at runtime. In this code you are not supporting this.

Comment: Yes. According to Head First Design Patterns.

Comment: Thank you! I will read up on inversion control, this is my first design pattern so it's encouraging I'm on the right track. Being able to change flight strategy during runtime would be simple enough with a setter I assume.

Comment: Also if anyone wants to add their comment as an answer I will mark it accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would point out a couple issues of semantics and terminology.

- It's confusing to have a method named `fly` that can be implemented as *not* flying. Naming the method `tryToFly` or documenting the method as merely an attempt are two ways of addressing this confusion. The software principle to reference here is Liskov Substitution.
- The base class does not *implement* one of the strategies; rather, it *composes* a strategy. The purpose of the Strategy pattern is to avoid subclassing through composition.
- To reiterate one of the comments, `Duck` should accept an instance of `IFly` directly in its constructor (or a setter method) rather than switching on an enum. Another goal of the Strategy pattern is to avoid branching logic.

The essence of the pattern is that you've avoided creating multiple subclasses of `Duck` by instead creating multiple implementations of `IFly`. This has the advantage that those `IFly` implementations can be reused without a complex inheritance hierarchy, e.g. `WILD` and `CITY` can share one strategy.

As mentioned in the comments, strategies also have the advantage that a `Duck` could change its strategy at runtime. For example, `IFly` might be implemented by `Soar` and `Glide` so that a `Duck` would switch between these different strategies depending on the wind.

Comment: Thanks, I see the problem with using a switch case and separation of responsibility/ the problematic potential for hundreds of enums in a large program. I'll make sure to work on ensuring clearer naming.

That last example is pretty cool with soaring vs gliding. Your post really tied up everything I misunderstood or was unsure about. Happy holidays!